# How do I use XComment when reading in an XML document?

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I'm using the following line to read in an XML document that may or may not have some comments bracketed by "`<!-- -->`" near the top of my XML file:

```
XDocument xe1 = XDocument.Load(filepath)
```

How do I read in the comments and store as a string?

I'm doing this in MS Visual Studio C#.

I know there's something called "XComment", but I can't find a simple example that uses it when reading in the XML (I can only find examples for creating a new XML file).

-Adeena

Answer (score 14):

Use this snippet to get all the comments from the XDocument:

```
var document = XDocument.Load("test.xml");

var comments =  from node in document.Elements().DescendantNodesAndSelf()
        where node.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Comment
        select node as XComment;
```

and this to parse only top-level comments:

```
var document = XDocument.Load("test.xml");

var comments = from node in document.Nodes()
           where node.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Comment
           select node as XComment;
```

Comment: Much more elegant than what I was trying.  Thank you!

Comment: Instead of checking if `node.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Comment` and then selecting the `node as XComment`, you can use OfType: `document.Nodes().OfType<XComment>()`; for comments below the root: `document.Root.Nodes().OfType<XComment>()`