# How to comment an XML file in C#

Tags: c#, xml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reading XML comments in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6277966/reading-xml-comments-in-c-sharp)

Is there a way in C# to write read in an XML file with comments and write those comments back out with the modified XML file?

I am using and XmlSerializer to deaserialize it. Then I am casting it to a class that was generated from an XSD using xsd.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189056(v=vs.95).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, comments are not automatically removed.

You will have to make an effort *not* to write them out.

So you can use XDocument, XmlDocument or XmlReader/XmlWriter.