# How to add a line under a xml element using c#

Tags: c#, configuration-files

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <configSections>
    ----------
    ----------
 </configSections>
 <appSettings>
     <add key="Name" Value="XXX">
     <add key="Age" Value="10">
     <!--<add key="Number" value="5"/>--><!--uncomment it-->
     <!--<add key="Class" value="10"/>-->
 </appSettings>
```

I want to uncomment the first commented line.

That's my code so far:

```
foreach (XmlElement xElement in xmlDoc.DocumentElement)
{
    if (xElement.Name == "appSettings")
    {
        foreach (XmlNode xNodes in xElement.ChildNodes)
        {
            if (xNodes.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Comment)
            {
                if (xNodes.InnerText.Contains("Number"))
                {
                    // Now the commented line is in xNodes.InnerText.
                    // How can i add this line in that xml file under appSettings?
                }
            }
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: do you mean to read the "Name" key? what do you mean by saying that you want to add a read line under appsettings element?

Comment: Are you trying to uncomment that line?

Comment: Really hard to understand. Please reformulate your question.

Comment: @danielhilgarth Yes. I want to uncomment.

Comment: @grkkarthick: Alright. Please show the code you have so far.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth foreach (XmlElement xElement in xmlDoc.DocumentElement) { if (xElement.Name == "appSettings") { foreach (XmlNode xNodes in xElement.ChildNodes) { if (xNodes.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Comment) { if (xNodes.InnerText.Contains("Number")) { //now the commented line is in xNodes.InnerText. How can i add this line in that xml file under appSettings? } } } break; } }

Comment: @grkkarthick: Are you attempting to modify your own app.config? Are you aware of the fact that it isn't really supported to do so? The changes will only come into effect after you restart your program

Comment: @DanielHilgarth No i'm going to edit in another app.exe.config file. Not in my own app.config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
var appSettingsNode = xmlDoc.DocumentElement
                            .ChildNodes
                            .Cast<XmlNode>()
                            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "appSettings");

if(appSettingsNode == null)
    return;

var commentedNodes = appSettingsNode.ChildNodes
                                    .Cast<XmlNode>()
                                    .Where(x => x.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Comment
                                                && (x.InnerText.Contains("Number")
                                                    || x.InnerText.Contains("Class")))
                                    .ToList();

foreach(var commentedNode in commentedNodes)
{
    var tmpDoc = new XmlDocument();
    tmpDoc.LoadXml(commentedNode.InnerText);
    appSettingsNode.ReplaceChild(xmlDoc.ImportNode(tmpDoc.DocumentElement, true),
                                 commentedNode);

    // Use this instead if you want to keep the commented line:
    // appSettingsNode.AppendChild(xmlDoc.ImportNode(tmpDoc.DocumentElement, true));
}
```

The important part is the one inside the `foreach` loop.
Here we load the commented node into a new `XmlDocument` (`tmpDoc`) to get it as a "real" `XmlNode` back. Then we simply replace the comment node (`commentedNode`) with our newly loaded node (`tmpDoc.DocumentElement`).

The rest is your original code, just beautified. Please note how I reduced the cyclomatic complexity by replacing the loops and ifs with LINQ queries.

Comment: Thank you Daniel!!! Great its working well. I have another doubt. How can I include one more key? Should I write the about commentNode line again with a new key? @DanielHilgarth

Comment: @grkkarthick: Please check update. For multiple keys, we need to use a `foreach` loop and change the second LINQ query a bit.

Comment: Thank you man. Great work. I had struggled with this from the past two weeks.

Comment: I think there is one extra ')' in the commentedNodes variable at last.

Comment: @grkkarthick: Fixed. The problem wasn't a `)` but two different names for the same variable `commentNode` inside the loop vs `commentedNode` in the loop header.

Comment: Sorry cannot get your answer.

Comment: ya get it. but i didnot use '(' after &&. will it make any mistake? I hope it does not a bug.

Comment: @grkkarthick: It will make a difference, you need to add the parenthesis where I put it. Otherwise you will also get nodes that contain `"Class"` but are not comment nodes. Note, `&&` has a higher precedence than `||`: `(false && false || true) != (false && (false || true))`

Comment: I have a issue with this. When i debug the second one does not get updated. It is still in commented line. :( @Daniel

Comment: @grkkarthick: Please see update. The second query was missing a `ToList` at the end.

Comment: @grkkarthick: LINQ queries internally use the [`yield` keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx) to support deferred execution. In our case, it means that without `ToList` the query won't be executed at the line it is defined, but it will be executed when using the result in the `foreach` loop. It will go something like this: (1) get and return first result of query. (2) execute our loop body (3) get and return second result of query (4) execute our loop body. The second result is requested from the already changed `xmlDoc` instance, leading to incorrect results.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read Name key this is how you do:

```
string myUsername = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Name"];
```

Answer (score 0):

In C# .net you would usually use `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` to read an appSetting from the config file.

If you are trying to read the commented out line from the web.config then you are going to have to write some custom code to do this.

[This answer should give you a good head start](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6278066/148998)