# Find Commented out text in XML File

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-xml

I am using Linq-to-XML to work with an xsd file (I am treating it like an xml file) and I am trying to pull out information about some enumerations.  Here is a snippet from the xsd file:

```
<xs:simpleType name="YorNA">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:int">
        <xs:enumeration value="1"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="-1"/>
        <!-- Yes -->
        <!-- Not Applicable -->
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

I can get the name and enumeration values, but I would like to put out the value meanings, which the writer put in commented out lines below the enumerations.  Is it possible to search specifically for these as nodes or will I just need to use some other method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have the [XElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.aspx) of the `<xs:enumeration>` node, you can search for comments as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6277966/reading-xml-comments-in-c-sharp) (I know, this example is C#, but is should not be difficult to adopt it in VB):

```cs
var comments = element.Descendants().OfType<XComment>();
foreach (XComment comment in comments) {...}
```