# c# Reading XML comment using XDocument

Tags: c#, xml

How to read xml comment when using XDocument?

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("joker.xml");
 foreach (XElement element in doc.Descendants("server"))
            {
//I use this to read server tag...
}



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<ho>
    <!-- For X use only -->
    <servers>
        <server NAME="xx" ></server>

    <!-- Dummy servers  -->
        <server NAME="xx" ></server>
        <server NAME="xx" ></server>
    </servers>
</ho>
```

Comment: It would be nice to see content of *joker.xml*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading XML comments in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6277966/reading-xml-comments-in-c-sharp)

Comment: not duplication since I want to do it in Xdocuemnt

Comment: By "comment" you mean you want to read the "NAME" attribute ? I'm not seeing anything called "comment" in the XML structure provided.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Node object is the primary data type for the entire DOM.

A node can be an element node, an attribute node, a text node, or any other of the node types explained in the ["Node types" chapter.](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_node.asp)

An XML element is everything from (including) the element's start tag to (including) the element's end tag.

```
     XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("");
       foreach (var node in xdoc.Descendants("servers").Nodes())
        {

            if (node is XComment)
            {
                //THEN  READ YOUR COMMENT 

            }

        }
```

Comment: You shouldn't **ALWAYS** use nodes.  In this case however you should.

Comment: sorry I will update  but in  this  case it's the best way to do it

Comment: Would that return `server` comments? That's just dump of all comments in file

Comment: @Julie node will have the entire xml file. and when it check whether node is Xcomment it says it's not

Comment: @JohnRyann my code work but it's more tricky  the code of   lazyberezovsky

Comment: @Julie, just curiosity , how would it work if it cant get pass the if node is XComment?

Comment: what you are looking  for an XComment it will not pass the XComment  I have Tried  it before I posted it it'works well

Comment: node has the entire XML file (joker.xml) and it doesnt pass if(node is XComment). it can not get inside the if statement

Answer (score 4):

Check node type when reading xml. If it's [`XComment`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xcomment%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) then you are reading comment. E.g. in your case previous node of server element will be comment:

```
foreach(var s in doc.Descendants("server"))
{
    var comment = s.PreviousNode as XComment;
    if (comment != null)
        Console.WriteLine(comment.Value); // outputs "Dummy servers"
}
```

Comment: no descendans will  return  an xelement which is different from  a node

Comment: @JulieShannon take a look on OP code. He wants to take comments for servers. Servers are elements.

Comment: ok but doing like this you are filtering all elements  did you understand  the  difference between node and element ?

Comment: @JulieShannon looks like you don't understand how my code works

Comment: ok  after you have  updated your code now it's working I  will upvote sorry  I  haven't see your update

Answer (score 0):

you will have to use the XmlReader.Create method and read it and switch between the nodes to indicate which node it is current reading
Dont be fooled by the Create method... it reads the xml file in question but creates an instance of the XmlReader object:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.create(v=vs.110).aspx

```
XmlReader xmlRdr = XmlReader.Create("Joker.XML");
// Parse the file
while (xmlRdr.Read())
{
    switch (xmlRdr.NodeType)
    {
        case XmlNodeType.Element:
            // Current node is an Xml Element
            break;
        case XmlNodeType.Comment:
            // This is a comment so do something with xmlRdr.value
```

... and so on

**PART 2** - for those who want to use LINQ (not that it makes a difference really)...

```
XDocument xml = XDocument.Load("joker.xml");
var commentNodes = from n in xml.Descendants("server")
                where n.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Comment
                select n;

foreach(XNode node in commentNodes)
{ 
  // now you are iterating over the comments it has found
}
```

Comment: no this is not an answer  with Xdocument you have the support of  Linq   to  xml he want a solution  to his code not a new way to do it

Comment: Sure but what difference does it make? LINQ just really makes it a little easier to read things. it doesnt change functionality. its another way of expressing things :). Furthermore the original question has not shown any usage on LINQ anyway.

Comment: A solution using XDocument is specifically asked for.

Comment: @Kevin - thanks. I was giving other alternatives. But I understand your comment and stand corrected :)