# XDocument is removing document comment

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

When I run  `<!-- This list contains names/words with specific casing - and specific to english only -->` will be removed in new destination.
Is there any way to prevent it from happening. I event tried with `XDocument.Root` same thing happened. 
Ps: I know method are not inside class :).

```
<!-- This list contains names/words with specific casing - and specific to english only -->
<ignore_list>
  <name>A.M.</name>
  <name>Aaron</name>
  <name>Abbie</name>
  <name>Abi</name>
  <name>Abigail</name>
  <name>Abolfazl</name>
  <name>Adam</name>
</ignore_list>
```

```
private static void EnGBNamesEtc()
{
        var listNames = new List<string>(){"some", "names");
        var xele = XElement.Load(@"C:\Users\ivandro\Source\subtitleedit\Dictionaries\en_GB_names_etc.xml");
        var names = listNames.Except(xele.Elements("name").Select(n => n.Value)).ToList();
        foreach (var newName in names)
        {
            xele.Add(new XElement("name", newName));
        }
        SaveToNewXml(xele, @"D:\Backup\en_GB_names_etc1.xml");
}

private static void SaveToNewXml(XElement xelem, string dest)
{
    XmlWriterSettings xws = new XmlWriterSettings { OmitXmlDeclaration = true, Indent = true };
    var ordered = xelem.Elements("name").OrderBy(element => element.Value).ToList();
    using (XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(dest, xws))
    {
        xelem.ReplaceAll(ordered);
        xelem.Save(xw);
    }
}
```

Comment: This SO might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20481741/c-sharp-reading-xml-comment-using-xdocument

Comment: Not related to your question, but: 1. `async` without `await` doesn't make much sense, and you're going to get a warning for that. 2. [You should avoid `async void` methods.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

Comment: the method is using `WebClient` to download content... I removed it to make it more simple and forgot async ;) @svick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's possibly because you're using `XElement` which only capable of representing single node (when you have two "root" nodes, `<ignore_list>` and the comment node). Use `XDocument` instead of `XElement` to keep the comment node, for example (I tried to keep minimal changes to your original code) :

```
private static async void EnGBNamesEtc()
{
        var listNames = new List<string>(){"some", "names");
        var xdoc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Users\ivandro\Source\subtitleedit\Dictionaries\en_GB_names_etc.xml");
        var names = listNames.Except(xdoc.Root.Elements("name").Select(n => n.Value)).ToList();
        foreach (var newName in names)
        {
            xdoc.Root.Add(new XElement("name", newName));
        }
        SaveToNewXml(xdoc, @"D:\Backup\en_GB_names_etc1.xml");
}

private static void SaveToNewXml(XDocument xdoc, string dest)
{
    XmlWriterSettings xws = new XmlWriterSettings { OmitXmlDeclaration = true, Indent = true };
    var ordered = xdoc.Root.Elements("name").OrderBy(element => element.Value).ToList();
    using (XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(dest, xws))
    {
        xdoc.Root.ReplaceAll(ordered);
        xdoc.Save(xw);
    }
}
```